# How to pass custom variables into drush site-install?

Tags: drush

I'm installing drush profile via:

```
drush site-install my_profile --db-url=db.url --account-name=admin --account-mail="admin@example.com" --site-mail="admin@example.com" --site-name="My Site"
```

**But how I can pass some variables into my_profile to initialize them with default values?**

In example I'd like to set specific file_public_path and file_private_path as some module fails to install because of the folder misconfiguration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add any additional settings you wish to pass to the profile in the following format (the key is in the form `[form name].[parameter name]`):

```
drush site-install my_profile install_configure_form.site_default_country=FR my_profile_form.my_settings.key=value
drush site-install my_profile install_configure_form.date_default_timezone="Europe/London" update_notifications.update_status_module=1
drush site-install my_profile variables.file_public_path="sites/default/files" variables.file_private_path="sites/default/private/files"
```

Then you can handle the variables in your profile code by either implementing [`hook_install_tasks`](https://api.drupal.org/hook_install_tasks) or [`hook_install_tasks_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/hook_install_tasks_alter) where you can access `$install_state` array which have information about the current installation state of your profile and your variables which can be accessed in `$install_state['forms']`.

In example (when set from drush via `variables.X="Y"`):

```
foreach ($install_state['forms']['variables'] as $name => $value) {
  variable_set($name, $value);
}
```

For `file_public_path` and `file_private_path`, it's not enough only to pass the variables, but you should prepare the directories as part of the installation script, e.g.:

```
file_prepare_directory($install_state['forms']['variables']['file_public_path'], FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);
file_prepare_directory($install_state['forms']['variables']['file_private_path'], FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);
file_prepare_directory($install_state['forms']['variables']['file_temporary_path'], FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);
drupal_static_reset('file_get_stream_wrappers'); // clear static cache for stream wrappers
```

This was implemented in drush as part of [Site Install: allow passing additional form parameters](https://www.drupal.org/node/1198956) feature request.

Please note that above feature it's only supported on Drupal 7 and above.